# Did ActiveState stop providing plain old MSI installer of Perl for Windows?

Tags: perl, activestate

I have a Windows 10 PC.
I want Perl.

I found the following blog post on theitsite:
https://community.activestate.com/t/new-msi-installer-for-activeperl/1626

"New MSI Installer for ActivePerl".

I didn't understand from it how and where should I get an EXE or MSI for Perl?
Where is the MSI / EXE?

This page : https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/
lets me use a PowerShell script, but I don't want it.

Should I manage the Windows environment variables myself?
I do not need multiple installations. just one.

Comment: I would recommend using Strawberry Perl instead. I had many different kinds of issues with ActiveState, and Strawberry just works, and you can use the native cpan tools to download all modules.

Answer (score 2):

Well -
I found that there is no MSI, also there is no PPM anymore.

There is - instead - the ActiveState package manager called simply "state".

It is first need to be installed via Windows CMD (Command line) -  more exactly - PowerShell.

After this each module is installed via "`state install XYZ`".

There's a need to sign up for an ActiveState Platform account.

It was change probably in July 2020 - two years ago, between perl 5.26 and Perl 5.28 from them.

I found this blog post:    https://community.activestate.com/t/new-msi-installer-for-activeperl/1626
Where ActiveState tell about their new way of installers - as follows:

- [It] is a web-style installer, which will provide a smaller initial download
- Includes the ActiveState Platform command line interface, the State Tool

Thats it for now.

And I managed to have Perl 5.36 from them, at last.